# Create a VCS macro

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to create an external tool in "File > Settings > Tools > External Tools" that uses the selected VCS change list number (Perforce in my case).

I don't see any VCS-related macros in "Insert Macro" dialog. 
Is there a way to create such a macro, or to create any macro, not event related to VCS, without creating a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Configure repository location from the `Import into Subversion`, or from `Check Out From Subversion` dialog box. Use the add button, which is available on the toolbar of the dialog box.

In the `SVN Repositories` tool window, do one of the following:
On the context menu of the window, choose New | Repository Location.
OR On the toolbar, click add button.
In the `New Repository Location` dialog box, specify URL of the repository, and click OK.

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-subversion-repository-location.html)

Comment: Thanks Rachel, but my question has nothing to do neither with SVN nor with repositories. Please open the "External Tools" dialog to see what I mean.